# androidアプリ開発で、android11以降の携帯とPCとのデータのやり取りについて

Tags: android, android-studio

現在、携帯アプリで作成したデータをPC側から取り込んで使用するシステムを作成しているのですが、android11以降の携帯では、セキュリティが強化されて、PC側からファイルを読み取れない状態になっています。
android11以降の携帯で、この動きを実現しようとした場合、GooglePlayに申請して承認をもらう必要があるようですが、1つの携帯でしか使用しないアプリに関しても、GooglePlayに申請して承認を受けないといけないのでしょうか。
別に世界に向けて売り出すようなアプリではなく、1つの携帯だけで稼働すればいい単純なアプリです。
何か他にやり方は無いのでしょうか。

※携帯からデータを取り出すPCはインターネットに接続できない環境にあるPCです

本来であれば、GoogleのPlayConsoleヘルプに問い合わせるべきなのでしょうが、一般的にアプリを売り出すつもりがないため、デベロッパーアカウントを作成しておらず、GooglePlayのコミュティでも、こう言った質問は受け付けていないとの事でした。

申し訳ありませんが、何か情報をお持ちの方、教えていただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 直接ではなくGoogleDriveとかのサービスに上げて間接的に行うとかを考えてみては？ 承認無しアプリで出来るかどうかは知りませんが、こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [AndroidアプリからGoogle Driveにファイルをバックアップする](https://zenn.dev/amegane/articles/e5d086f7ebaf8d)

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！
- 現在お使いの具体的なAndroidのバージョン
- アプリケーション開発に使っているIDEやSDK(バージョン含む)
- スマートフォンとPCの接続方法(USB type-Cで接続しているか、それとも無線(Bluetooth, Wi-Fi))
などを追記していただき、タグに`android-studio`等をつけると回答が得られやすいかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。申し訳ありません。情報を書き忘れていました。データを取り込みたいPCはインターネットに接続できない環境なのです。本文に追記しておきます。

Comment: それならばさらに間接的な手段で、インターネットに接続できるPCでWeb上のサービスからダウンロードして、USBメモリでコピーするとかRS232Cケーブル経由で接続して転送するとかを考えてみては？ そういったコピーや接続も出来ないPCならそもそも携帯を接続することも出来ない(してはならない)ような気がしますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。携帯はそのアプリ以外は使わないようにして運用する予定でした。

Comment: 間接的な手法であれば実現可能だと思いますが、やはり、携帯からデータを抽出する為には、一般的にアプリを売り出す予定がなくても、GooglePlayへの申請と承認が必要になってしまうのですね。

Answer (score 0):

何かしらの外部ストレージを差し込んで、その中に保存をPC側からしておいて
アプリ側からその外部ストレージを読みに行くとかできるんじゃないでしょうか…？

後は、アプリのパーミッションでストレージ読み書きを許可してあげればいいかと思います。
やっぱり、アプリ内のストレージには外部から読み書きできないんですかね…。
昔はできたんですが。